# Source file issue with File Upload Control

Tags: c#, web-controls

I have a problem with a web form project.

The project is set to use the local IIS web server to run the application.

In the form, I have a file upload control defined in the aspx markup page.

However, when I try to upload a file, the program always thinks that the file is located in the IIS Express folder, whatever the location of the file actually is.

I have tried to change the settings to make it use the visual studio development server but I hit the same issue. The program then always thought that the file to upload was in the development server folder.

How can I fix that?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you show the code that use that control?

Comment: Here is the markup code: <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"/> I just want to be able to load assemblies to the server using the control. The code behind is string path = Path.GetFullPath(this.FileUpload1.FileName.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(path);
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);